# Can data entry to one field be made dependent on entered data of another field in the same table in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access

I have designed a table which has the fields of ID, Impact, Impact_if_Other. Impact is designed as a dropdown box in Form. I want Impact_if_Other field to be editable in the form only if user selects "Other" from the Impact dropdown. How can this be achieved in Form Design?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can use Conditional Formatting to enable/disable Impact_if_Other textbox based on value of Impact. However, if user changes Impact from Other to something else, will need code (macro or VBA) to remove value (if any) from Impact_if_Other.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below `VBA` codes. Write below codes to ComboBox `Impact` `After_Update` event.

```
IF Me.Impact="Other" Then
   Me.ImpactOther.Locked=False
   'Me.ImpactOther.Enabled=False
ELSE
   Me.ImpactOther.Locked=True
   'Me.ImpactOther.Enabled=True
END IF
```

Comment: Dear Harun24HR, this works all right, thanks! However, it lets me enter data into Impact_if_Other even if I haven't chosen anything from the Impact dropdown/combobox. Can we tackle this as well? My apologies as I am new to Access & VBA!

Comment: Either use Conditional Formatting as advised in comment under question or also use code in form Current event. Code simplified to one line: `Me.ImpactOther.Enabled = Me.Impact = "Other"`

Comment: You would also have to call this code in the OnCurrent event.

Comment: @vgb17 By default you can lock/enabled the `ImpactOther` textbox. From property sheet under data tab you can set lock/enabled to `False`. As @Gustav suggested, you can write these codes to form `On Current` event.